# Unable to redirect the URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a `GetCustomerDetails` method in a controller, in which I am trying redirect to another page. But I was unable to redirect, and it is staying in the same page from where I am trying to redirect.

```
public ActionResult GetCustomerDetails()
{
      .......
      // return Redirect("/Quote/QuoteDetails?sc_mode=preview");
      string link = "/quote/QuoteDetails";
      return Redirect(link);
      // return Redirect("../View/quote/QuoteDetails");  
      // return Redirect("~/View/quote/QuoteDetails");            
}
```

and I tried some of the commented options(above) but still I was unable to redirect.

Can any body help me in this issue?

Comment: Could you please try `RedirectToAction("QuoteDetails", "Quote")`?

Comment: we dont want to call any action method in your case. So i am looking for redirect option

Comment: Everything is an action.  You can't call views directly, you must call an action that returns the view you want.

Comment: @user2522503 A *redirect* is a *redirection to another action*. Maybe you want your action to send a different view as a result, is that the case?

Comment: yes we want to redirect to diff page

Answer (score 4):

Use `RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller")` method:

```
return RedirectToAction("QuoteDetails", "quote");
```

Comment: we dont want to call any action method in your case. So i am looking for redirect option.